# Jquery Runtime error while using Datepicker

Tags: jquery

I just used Jquery Datepicker in my Web Application.

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("[id$=txtDate]").datepicker({

            showOn: 'button',
            altField: '[id$=HiddenField1]'

        });

        if ($("[id$=HiddenField1]").attr("Value").length > 0) {

            $("[id$=txtDate]").datepicker("setDate", new Date($("[id$=HiddenField1]").attr("Value")));

        }

    });

</script>
```

But while run the application the below line got error

```
  if ($("[id$=HiddenField1]").attr("Value").length > 0)
```

Error is: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Pls help me how to solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
if($("[id$=HiddenField1]").val().length > 0)
```

This will fix your concern.